# Spread operator inside setState is executed twice instead of once

Tags: reactjs

[image]

When a user submits the form, onSubmitMessage() is called which in turn emit a event to socket on server side and when a response is sent to client side it executes the setState function twice instead of once.

Client side code

```
state = {
        message: '',
        currentChat: []
    }
onChangeMessage = (event) => {

        this.setState({
            message: event.target.value
        });   
    }

onSubmitMessage = (event) => {     
        event.preventDefault();

        this.setState({
            message: ''
        });

        console.log(this.state.message);


        socket.emit('inputMessage', {
            username: this.props.username,
            message: this.state.message
        });

        socket.on('currentsocketchat', (data) => {

            console.log('data is ',data.message);

            this.setState({
                currentChat: [...this.state.currentChat, data.message]
            }, () => console.log(this.state.currentChat));

        });

    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="inputbar">
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitMessage}>
                    <input 
                    ref={this.inputRef}
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="Enter message" 
                    value={this.state.message}
                    onChange={this.onChangeMessage} />
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }

//Server side code

socket.on('inputMessage', (data) => {
        console.log(data.username, data.message);

        const newChat = new Chat({
            name: data.username,
            message: data.message,
        });

        newChat.save().then(() => {
            socket.emit('currentsocketchat', newChat);
            // socket.broadcast.emit('broadcastchat', data);

        }).catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
        })

    });
```

When I submit form with input value "Hiii", then output of this.state.currentChat should be ["Hiii"]. When I again send a "Hello", 
then the output should be ["Hii","Hello"]
Instead I am getting the output as ["Hii","Hello", "Hello"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a listener to the socket message every time `onSubmitMessage` is executed. So the second time you submit, the callback is invoked twice, the 3rd time you submit it will be invoked 3 times.
Move the `socket.on('currentsocketchat'...` into `componentDidMount` and this should work.

Comment: I am not able to understand that on second submit how the callback is invoked twice?

Comment: This is because `onSubmitMessage` registers a listener every time is called. So the first time you submit, it will register a first listener; the second time you submit it will  register a second listener and so on. When you get a message from the socket `currentsocketchat` all the registered callback will be invoked, so 1 the first time, 2 the second and so on

Comment: ya I got it. Thanks a lot @Dario

Comment: No problems. If this solves your issue, please accept the answer